# Define prototype for {...} objects only

Tags: javascript, object, key, prototype

Is it possible to define a prototype only for {}-Objects?

**In Javascript, almost everything is an object.**

```
Object.prototype.test = function() {
    alert("test");
}
```

All objects (including Number, String and Array) will have this method.
But I only want this for an struct object. > {...} <

You can first create all prototypes for the object and delete it from others like Number, String and Array.

```
// Overwrite
Array.prototype.test = undefined; // or delete property
```

This "works" ... The prototype is overwritten. But the key still exists.

```
// Show all keys
for (key in arr)
{
    alert(key); // print index of array AND keynames
}
```

I looking for the most elegant way to do this.

Comment: Don't modify the `Object` prototype unless you intend for the property to be available on every object, which you stated you do not want. Regardless, modifying the `Object` prototype is almost always a bad idea. Instead, you should place the property on the prototype of some class that you control, and inherit from that as needed.

Comment: Also, deleting the property from the `Array` prototype won't do what you want. Calling `test` on an array will still run the function, because it will go up the prototype chain and simple call `test` on the `Object` prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/x2wysox8/

Comment: don't delete property `test` from `Array.prototype`, just throw an error on call, if you want to limit access to the `Object.prototype.test` method. But adding methods to `Object.prototype` is bad practice, and think twice, before doing this

Comment: Indeed! Delete is not the correct way. Thanks! Overwriting works. But it's not the best way. Unfortunately the object {} has no own name like number or string. A similar issue with arrays. Typeof array is "object" not "array". It is really a pity. You have to check with instance of or Array.isArray. But that's another topic. :)

Comment: Why don't you do: `Object.test = function(){};`? and inside the function check for the type of the caller, and then you call the function like: `Object.test({a:"b"});`

Comment: @Ziki: Of course you can do this. But this is not the exactly topic. :) But a good solution for a universal method.

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly do not want to modify the `Object` prototype. This [MDN article on JavaScript inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes) sums it up nicely:

> One mis-feature that is often used is to extend Object.prototype or one of the other built-in prototypes.
>
> This technique is called monkey patching and breaks encapsulation. While used by popular frameworks such as Prototype.js, there is still no good reason for cluttering built-in types with additional non-standard functionality.

In your example, removing the `test` property from `Array` will not have the desired effect. When `Array.test` is called, it will simply search up the prototype chain and execute `Object.test`. This is illustrated by the following code:

```
Object.prototype.test = function () {
    alert('In test');
}

delete Array.prototype.test;

//Calls Object.test and shows the alert
[].test();
```

Instead, you could create a base class that you control and inherit from it as needed. See below for a working demonstration.

```js
function MyBaseClass() {
  this.test = function () {
    log('In test');
  };
}

function Shape() {
  this.shapeAction = function () {
    log('Shape action');
  };
}

Shape.prototype = new MyBaseClass();

function Square() {
  this.squareAction = function () {
    log('Square action');
    this.shapeAction();
  };
}

Square.prototype = new Shape();

//Test function can be called on Square, but not on Array
var s = new Square();

s.squareAction();
s.shapeAction();
s.test();

try {
  [].test();
}
catch (e) {
  log('Exception when trying to run Array.test: ' + e);
}

//Log function for demonstration purposes
function log(s) {
  var e = document.createElement('p');
  e.innerHTML = s;
  document.body.appendChild(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with `Array.prototype.test = undefined;` you methods value sets to `undefinied`, and this will not delete it.

If you realy want to delete method(property) use `delete Array.prototype.test;`

p.s. But in this case (with `{}` object) -> you can't get what you whant with `delete`.

`Array.prototype` is inherited from `Object.prototype`, and after deleting `Array.prototype.test` your code will find `Object.prototype.test` and call it.

I think the best way to make what you want is to make something like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'test', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: true,
  value: function(test) { alert('In test' + test); }
});

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'test', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: function() { throw new Error('You can\'t do it!'); }
});

try {
    var a = [];
    var keys = "";

    for (key in a) {
        keys += key + ', '; // get all keys
    }
    // call array test method -> will throw exception
    a.test('from array');

} catch (e) {
    // check keys -> test is not here
    console.log("Error: " + e.message + ' ' + "KEYS: " + keys);
}

var b = {};
// and this will work
b.test('from object');
```

Comment: This won't prevent `test` from being called on `Array`. The prototype chain will find the `test` function on the `Object` prototype and call that: http://jsfiddle.net/x2wysox8/

Answer (score 0):

Well although you can change Object prototype, this is highly not recommended. That's because all libraries you'll ever use expect that Object is untouched. That can lead to very hard to trace bugs and unexpected behavior by some libraries.

What you need is to learn how to do correct object orientation in JS. That's a very confusing subject for js starters. I recommed you read the excelent "The Principles Of Object-Oriented JavaScript" from Nicolas Zakas and the "You don't know JS" book series from Kyle Simpson.

But you can have a good start with my explanation on how to do Object Orientation in javascript in my blog: http://www.ideasaboutcode.com/object-orientation-in-javascript/

hope it helps.